# IOS: scrollview disabled under an ImageView with animation

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

In my app, I have a scrollview with "paging enabled" and when I chose a page an imageview start its animation in this way

```
- (void) beginWinAnimation{
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5
                 animations:^{successView.alpha = 1.0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 

                 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5
                 animations:^{successView.alpha = 0;}];
                 }];}
```

During this animation I can see the scrollview under this successView and I can move scrollview page; I want that during animation you can't move the scrollview but only when animation is finished, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. When the animation starts set `[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];` After your animation is complete set it back to `YES`.

So in your code, it will look like -

```
- (void) beginWinAnimation{

[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];

[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5
                 animations:^{
                     successView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:2.5
                         animations:^{successView.alpha = 0;}
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
                             [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
                         }]; 
                 }];}
```

See if this works.

Comment: This is a completely correct answer; I guess toggling `userInteractionEnabled` which `UIScrollView` inherits from `UIView` as an alternative to `scrollEnabled` is worth mentioning as a more general approach.

Comment: since @blackguardian wants only the scroll to be blocked it makes sense to block that only. We could have achieved the same behavious by switching off `userInteractionEnabled` but then everything on the screen becomes untappable. That leads to some ugly usability issues. So...

Comment: it works but there is a problem, the scroll is enabled when alpha change by 1 to 0; when alpha change by 0 to 1 it's ok

Comment: is that now what you wanted ?

Comment: yes the scroll should be disabled ever when animation is running

Comment: @blackguardian ok changed the code try that. Basically, what I have changed is made the `scrollView` scroll enable only after alpha change by 1 to 0; when alpha change by 0 to 1 is done.